# Apple Mach-O Linker Error iOS 7

Tags: xcode, ios7, linker-errors

i try to build a small iOS app with dreamfactory as backend.
When i build the app with the librarys from dreamfactory i'm getting a mach-o linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me.
Sorry for my bad englisch.

Comment: It could be that this library does not support 64-bit, are you sure that it does?

Comment: @PatrickGoley Even when i choose 32bit Simulator i'm getting this error but with i386.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet, so I'll have to post here.  This was addressed already in this thread:  https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/ios-sdk/issues/1